# Does 64-bit java 1.7 ignore the minimum heap size flag?

Tags: java, memory-management, 64-bit

java -Xms is apparently not having an affect on the amount of memory the java process consumes during a run.

I have an app that consumes about 1Gb from the system point of view.  I tried setting -Xms2048m (and -Xmx4096m) and I see absolutely no change in memory consumption.

The hotspot docs claim the heap size is bounded below by the Xms value or the default.

The only thing I can think of is maybe the process cannot grab a contiguous block of memory, so it grabbed all it could and then will allocate more later, or maybe windows is not letting it have that much memory to start with.  (64-bit windows 7)

(I don't need this for anything, it is just something curious I noticed)

Comment: Are you setting -Mmx to an appropriate value (ie. mx > ms) ?

Comment: @sw1nn - yes, I'm setting mx to 4096m.  I don't think the vm will start if ms > mx.

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage of the Java process?

Comment: windows is showing you actual consumed memory that has data in it, not allocated address space

Comment: @Affe - what is the best way to determine allocated space?  And please reply as an answer so you can get credit :)

Comment: Have you tried `-Xincgc` as a flag instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default memory usage windows task manager shows you is not what's allocated in the processes virtual memory space.  It's how much that process has actually written into the virtual space that has had to be mapped onto real memory.  If you enable the column for 'Commit Size' in your task manager that will show what is actually considered "used" from the perspective of your processes's virtual address space.  (roughly Xms + permsize + size of VM and system stuff itself.)

Answer (score 1):

For Java 1 try with `-ms` and `-mx`

Since Java2 you can use `-Xms` and `-Xmx`

My experience is, that `-ms` and `-mx works also in Java2. See http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5578

Answer (score 0):

The JVM need a continuous region of memory for the heap.  This means it allocates the maximum size as virtual memory on startup.  This is not as bad as it sounds as the OS only allocates main memory to the application as it uses it, (not when it allocates virtual memory)

If you look at the amount of memory used in a tool like VisualVM, you can find that even with overhead of 150 - 500 MB, the size is less than the minimum size.  This is because Java doesn't just use the minimum size if it doesn't have a use for it.

Instead the minimum size is the point below which it makes only minor attempts to clean up memory. (You may see it perform minor GCs)  In most cases this means the application will use the minimum size very quickly.  However, a "hello world" program will not use the minimum size.

> maybe windows is not letting it have that much memory to start with

The JVM will fail to start if it cannot allocate the maximum size as a continuous block. (This was a common problem on 32-bit Window, such that the limit could be 1.5 GB or as low as 1.2 GB)